# disable control character input from keyboard shortcuts in notepad++

Tags: character-encoding, keyboard, notepad++, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to disable the input of control characters in NotePad++? For example if I press the following keyboard shortcuts it inserts a control character into my file.

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> `[SOH]`
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> `[SUB]`
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> `[CAN]`
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> `[ETX]`
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> `[SYN]`

I use other NotePad++ keyboard shortcuts as well as AutoHotKey extensively. I have had some wrist strain and have been trying to limit my use of the mouse and other repetitive motions. There are instances when I inadvertently hit one of the above keystrokes instead of a different shortcut, thereby entering an unwanted character in my code that I have to remove. Is there any easy way to disable these hotkeys from inputing these characters in Notepad++?

It seems like other basic text editors like Windows Notepad will either not enter these characters or not show them when editing, so it seems like there should be a way to disable the input of these types of characters.

Other questions that I found were about removing these characters from output or how to input these characters. Other general questions about Windows keyboard settings were talking about advanced key settings under keyboards to prevent the <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> shortcut to switch between input languages although I only have one keyboard there. I want to find a way to easily prevent myself from accidentally entering in these characters.

[Displaying Control character [SOH] as blank space or else in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804855/displaying-control-character-soh-as-blank-space-or-else-in-notepad)

[How to disable 'shift'+'alt' keyboard shortcut in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27926336/how-to-disable-a-keyboard-shortcut-in-notepad)

Answer (score 2):

Code below is written in AutoHotkey and disables all the offending key combos:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class Notepad++
^+a::return
^+z::return
^+x::return
^+c::return
^+v::return

#IfWinactive

; other hotkeys go here or define another window
```